# Can't edit upon clicking "Edit" in a review

Tags: bug, editing, review

I was reviewing a possible "Low Quality Post" which could use some improved formatting. So I clicked "Edit" and got this screen:

[image: image of edit situation]

So far, so good. But when I tried to edit the title or the body, I couldn't: the text in the boxes couldn't be altered.

Going to the main site interface and manually editing that question worked just fine, though.

---

Reproduction information:

- Windows 7 Pro
- Chrome latest (you know, with that annoying new "Apps" button on your bookmarks bar)
- The problem does not occur in the "Close Votes" queue (at least, not for me)

Comment: Ah, so I am not the only one (with the annoying new "Apps" button on my bookmark bar).

Comment: @Karl I've just found the checkmark to disable the icon, in the dropdown menu (right-click "Apps" button, somewhere at the bottom).

Comment: Right-click on the bookmark bar and uncheck *show apps shortcut*.